# How do I display multiple lists side by side?

Tags: html, css

Hello I am having issues with a set of 5 ul list -

I am just trying to get them all to be vertically aligned across the top where "giant breeds" is.

I took out the HTML because it is quite long, but I added a [js fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/nvNTb/39/).

The CSS:

```css
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lilita+One|Questrial|Sriracha" rel="stylesheet"> 

body ul {
font-family: Questrial;
font-size: 26px;
}

body h1 {
font-family: Questrial;
font-size: 26px;
}

span {
font-family: Questrial;
font-size: 16px;
}

ul { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 2px; 
    list-style-type: none; 
    float: left; 
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: inherit;
}
```

Comment: <h1> elements are block level element, they will take up the width of there containers (in this case the <body>).  Try putting each group in its own container with `display: inline-block` (like a span).

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap each h1 and ul in a div together. Then apply the floats to those divs.
Change in css, remove from ul and add to div:

```
 div{
     float:left
 }
```

Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nvNTb/40/

Answer (score 0):

I would opt to work without floats to keep the document flow intact. I've used a flexbox to align the divs around the `h1` and `ul`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/nvNTb/41/)